# The option to select similar area is not available

Tags: mesh, faces

I have a mesh and I want to find the similar faces. With face selected I click on shift+G and there is no option for similar area option. Where the option gone.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not in face selection mode you can't select faces because Blender can't determine any area to select by.

Switch to face selection mode and the option should become available

Answer (score 0):

Try **Shift + G** and menu will be pop up for you :) Best of luck

Updated:

You are on **Vertex select** mode, as shown below:
[image]

Please switch to **Face select** mode as marked below:
[image]

Comment: yeah i did it but same menu as shown above

Comment: You are on the 'Vertex select' mode right now, please try to switch to the 'Face select' mode and you will get all options back.